# Is $E(\varepsilon_i|x_i)=0$ weaker than $Cov(\varepsilon_i, x_i)=0$?

Tags: least-squares, covariance

In the context of ordinary least squares model $y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_i + \varepsilon_i$ some authors assume $E(\varepsilon_i|x_i)=0$ and some authors assume $Cov(\varepsilon_i, x_i)=0$.

Is the assumption $E(\varepsilon_i|x_i)=0$ weaker than $Cov(\varepsilon_i, x_i)=0$?

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful, because in this context there are *two* possible distinct meanings of "$E[\varepsilon_i\mid x_i]:$" one is a conditional probability and the other is not.  The answer might very well rest on that distinction.

Comment: Yes sorry, the Expectation is supposed to represent conditional probability. In written form: The expectation of ei given xi is equal to zero

Comment: @whuber what is the other meaning other than conditional expectation? And, why are you and OP referring it as conditional probability, instead of expectation?

Comment: @Gunes You're right: I should have written "conditional expectation" instead of "conditional probability." Thank you for clarifying that.  The other interpretation of the notation is that $x_i$ is simply a number, not a random variable.  The resulting expression is an expectation, not a conditional expectation.  This is the usual model of any designed experiment, for instance, where $x_i$ is determined by the experimenter.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use $x$ instead of $x_i$ and $u$ instead of $\varepsilon_i$.

No, $E(u|x)=0$ is stronger than $Cov(u, x)=0$.
Here is the proof:
$$
Cov(u, x) = E(ux) - E(u)E(x) = E(E(ux|x))-E(E(u|x))E(x)= E(xE(u|x)) - 0 = 0 
$$
But $E(u|x) = 0$ is weaker than independence of $u$ and $x$. For counterexample consider $u$ that takes values $-1$, $1$, $2$, $-2$ with equal probabilities and $x=u^2$.

Comment: You seem to equate zero covariance with "independence," but that's not correct.

Comment: @whuber, no :) I just say that: independence of $u$ and $x$ implies $E(u|x)=0$, which in turn, implies $Cov(u, x)=0$.

Comment: The OP (not me) says $E(u|x)=0$ is weaker than $Cov(u,x)=0$ and asks for explanations why. This claim is false, and I give a proof that zero covariance is weaker and follows from zero conditional expected value.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  It would help to include those clarifications in the post itself, because in its current form it is ambiguous.